# Падение скорости работы с БД после переноса в External Storage

Tags: android, sqlite

Имеется **одна** БД, которая при первом запуске копируется из `Assets`.

Если её копировать в приватную папку, то скорость работы нареканий не вызывает.

Если её скопировать в не приватную папку (например, Documents), скорость падает минимум раза в 2.

Подчёркиваю. Это **одна и та же БД**. В обоих случаях **одни и те же запросы**.

С чем может быть связана такая аномалия скорости? Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какие запросы-то?

Comment: SQL конечно же.

Comment: (¬‿¬ ) селекты/инсерты?

Comment: И то и другое и апдейты. И БД и логика не менялись. Менялось только расположение файла БД.

Comment: Разное железо накопителей, файловые системы, драйвера, системы обработки привелегий доступа - всё это может сказываться на скорости работы.

Answer (score 1):

По части ответа на сам вопрос - я бы поставил на особенности самого устройства. Физически по разному реализованная памать, оттого и разная скорость.

Могу предложить такой сценарий, как вариант заметного ускорения базы за счет увеличения времени запуска:

```
//создаем базу в оперативной памяти
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(":memory:", null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

//присоединяем к ней базу с диска
database.rawExecSQL("attach '" + db.getPath());

//копируем содержимое базы в память

Cursor cursor = query("select * from source.sqlite_master");
int sqlID = cursor.getColumnIndex("sql");
int typeID = cursor.getColumnIndex("type");
int tablenameID = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
String tableName, type;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    type = cursor.getString(typeID);
    switch (type) {
        case "table": {
            database.rawExecSQL(cursor.getString(sqlID));
            tableName = cursor.getString(tablenameID);
            database.rawExecSQL("insert into main." + tableName + " select * from source." + tableName);
            break;
        }
    }
}

//открепляем базу с диска
database.rawExecSQL("detach database source");
```

Если есть индексы - добавляем case под индексы. Но при таком подходе на диск индексы смысла сохранять нет, лучше сохранить куда-то команды для их создания. Все равно они будут генерироваься в базу в опертивке при каждом запуске.

В активити в onStop или по мере работы с базой вызываем сохранение изменений на диск